# How do I check if the 'destructive' button was pressed (UIActionSheet - iPhone)?

Tags: iphone, delegates, uiactionsheet

I'm trying to work out the line of code I need to use in order to determine if the 'destructive' button has been press in a UIActionSheet.

I've had a look around and found the delegate method...

```
 - (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

.. and I've also managed to find `[myActionSheet destructiveButtonIndex]`, I'm just not sure how to put the two together. This is what I have tried so far with no success:

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == destructiveButtonIndex) 
    {
        // Do something...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You were very close with your code. The implementation you're looking for is:

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == actionSheet.destructiveButtonIndex) 
    {
        // Do something...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you - that's what I was looking for. I knew I was close ;)

Answer (score -2):

You have to check like below

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 0) 
    {
        // Do something...
    }
  else if (buttonIndex == 1)
  {

  }
}
```

Comment: Wrong. The OP is looking for the destructiveButton specifically. There is a property on UIActionSheet to find this.